# Can I view external Go libraries with VSCode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'd like to switch to using VSCode full time, but the one thing keeping me on IntellijIDEA is its ability to view Go standard and all dependency libraries in External Libraries of project which located in $GOROOT or $GOPATH/pkg/mod on the filesystem. In particular, I'd like it to work with Go. As of yet, I've been unable to find a suitable solution to view Go standard and all dependency libraries in the Explorer of VSCode.

Comment: You can use CTRL+click to navigate to files of both the standard lib and external libs. Isn't this enough? What do you expect?

Comment: @icza I know how to do this, but what I really need is to list external libraries in the Explorer in VSCode,  so I can view some related code from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this plug-in "go mod explorer"

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a few manual steps if you use [Workspaces](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces).

Once in a workspace (see link above if unfamiliar with the concept), you can use the GUI (*Add folder to workspace*) or, what I prefer, the integrated terminal (see example below).

From the integrated terminal:

```
$ code --add /path/to/"external library"
```

and the related library will appear in the explorer.

The added paths will be remembered by the workspace on vscode close and restart :-)

Comment: The Go language server is currently not supported in a multi-root set-up with different GOPATHs. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-go/issues/2431

Comment: That issue is closed. It points to two other issues, https://github.com/golang/go/issues/30841 and https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29174, both closed as solved. The procedure I proposed works for me. The language server might be confused in a few cases but overall works. Have you tried?

Comment: Yes, I have already tried by adding $GOROOT/src (the GO standard library) to the same workspace, and it turned out "The Go language server is currently not supported in a multi-root set-up with different GOPATHs." reported to me by VSCode. The gopls server failed to work.

Comment: What happens if you run vscode with GOROOT unset (what I have) ?